# PHP Laravel - how to select mysql table names by name template

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$nameTemplate=“prefix_“;
$tables = DB::select(“SHOW TABLES LIKE ‘$nameTemplate%’“);
```

this returns as prefix_somename, so prefixanothername too. How to do to only first result returns?

```
$nameTemplate = ‘prefix_‘;
$tables = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
$tables = collect($tables);
$tables->contains(function ($item) use ($nameTemplate) {
    return (strpos($item, $nameTemplate) !== false);
});
```

this returns all tables. Where is an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to filter the results, like this:

```
$tables = collect($tables)->filter(function($item) use ($nameTemplate) {
     return strpos($item, $nameTemplate) !== false;
});
```

`$tables` here should contain only the tables based on your filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found that first part of question expression works if to use backslash before "_"

```
$nameTemplate=“prefix\_“;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$nameTemplate="prefix_";

        $tableNames = \Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();

        foreach ($tableNames as $tableNameValue) 
        {
            if (strpos($tableNameValue, $nameTemplate) !== false) 
            {
                dd('table found in serach criteria ');
            }
            else
            {
                dd('table not found in serach criteria ');
            }

        }
```